# amcharts v3 removing "show all" at the top right corner

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I have a simple bullet chart and everything works fine except that pesky image with a magnifying glass saying show all at right-hand top corner. Is there a setting in amcharts v3 to remove this?

Code

```
var chartobject = {
            type: 'serial',           
            theme: 'none',
            titles: [{ text: 'title goes here' }],
            dataProvider: plotData,
            trendLines: [],
            dataDateFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
            categoryField: 'xValue',
            rotate: false,
            startDuration: 1,
         
            categoryAxis: {
                axisAlpha: 1,
                gridAlpha: 0,
                labelRotation: 90,
                axisColor: '#006CA0',
                color: '#006CA0',
                parseDates: true,
                dateFormats: [
                    { "period": 'DD', "format": 'DD/MM/YY' },
                    { "period": 'MM', "format": 'DD/MM/YY' },
                    { "period": 'YYYY', "format": 'DD/MM/YY' }
                ]
            },            

            valueAxes: [{
                "id": 'ValueAxis-1',
                "position": 'left',
                "axisAlpha": 0,
                "title": '',
                "stackType": 'none'
            }],

            graphs: graphs

       
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set [`zoomOutText`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/reference/amrectangularchart/#zoomOutText_property) to an empty string.

```
{
  type: 'serial',
  zoomOutText: '',
  // ...
}
```